How to calculate difference in the same column
I have three SharePoint list columns named as follows:

Athletes name as choice
Counters as date time
Difference as calculated field.

I want the formula to calculate the difference between the counters of each athlete in the calculated field "Difference". When the athletes do a race I enter the time in the "counters" field and the formula should automatically calculates the difference between the recorded time and the previous time.
Picture : https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZB0310ZSIpABPqhmQJEGzKsVald1jzezO4X

If I understood your question correctly, I think you are trying to create a calculated column based on same column (counters) values from 2 different list items/rows for same "Athletes name".
So, I don't think it is possible using SharePoint calculated columns.
SharePoint Calculated columns has below limitations:


You cannot reference a value in a row other than the current row.
You cannot reference a value in another list or library.



Documentation: Introduction to SharePoint formulas and functions

You can customize the SharePoint online list form using Power Apps and write custom logic to calculate difference as per your requirements inside Power Apps customized list form using formulas.
Reference: Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps

Similar threads:

Question on formula
Can I use a calculated column to show whether a vehicle check submission has already been completed on any given day
SharePoint list calculated column to sum values from another column

